# Magento 2. How do I setup a coupon code with free shipping > $X. Customer to pay full shipping fee if Cart < $X

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am using Magento ver. 2.3.5.

- I would like to setup a coupon code for free shipping > $50
- If the total order is less than $50, customer must pay shipping fee

The reason for this setup is that I am giving 40% off matching items in the cart also using this coupon code only

- If customer spends $50 or more, customer gets free shipping + 40% off.
- If customer spends less than $50, customer only gets 40% off. Customer pay shipping.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't natively allow you to apply multiple coupon codes to a specific order. So having a coupon code for free shipping AND using a coupon code for 40% off wouldn't work.

What will work, and works natively in 2.4 and should work in 2.3, is using two separate cart price rules. You would set up a generic rule to provide free shipping on carts with a subtotal of greater than $50. Then you'd create a normal coupon code rule that applies the 40% off to the specific items.

Here are two example rules:

1. **Generic Free Shipping Rule**

   - Coupon: None
   - Conditions:

     - Subtotal > $50
   - Actions:

     - Free Shipping:

       - For shipments with matching items
2. **40% off Rule**

   - Coupon: *Whatever you want the code to be*
   - Conditions: *Whatever your rule conditions are*
   - Actions:

     - Apply: Percent of product discount
     - Discount Amount: 40

The reason this works is because the cart price rules operate at the cart level. While the discount is calculated per-product, they are combined into one discount that is applied *after* the subtotal. This would not work if you used catalog price rules, since these types of rules will adjust the price of the line item which will affect your subtotal.

Comment: Thank you Brett. We don't want to offer Generic Free Shipping Rule (1) above. This would mean any customer on the website will get Free Shipping > $50. I take your answer as what I am trying to achieve is not possible with native Magento.

Comment: You can still condition the free shipping to $50 minimum of certain products, but it wouldn’t be something they opt into with a coupon code.  Outside of this, you’re into custom development territory for your business case. It’s possible to achieve, just not natively.